# The motivation behind the Factory Method design pattern

Tags: design-patterns, factory-method, factory-pattern

I'm learning about the Factory Method Desing Pattern and I'm having a hard time to understand exactly what it tries to solve and how.

Let's first introduce the example that Wikipedia uses to have a basis for the discussion.

[image]

So basically the products are `MagicRoom` and `OrdinaryRoom`, both derive from `Room`. And for the creators we have the base class/interface `MazeGame` which defines the method `makeRoom`, and the subclasses are `MagicMazeGame` and `OrdinaryMazeGame`. Now the client may either:

```
MazeGame game = new OrdinaryMazeGame()
or
MazeGame game = new MagicMazeGame()
```

Ok this is so we can talk about some example.

Now, Wikipedia describes the motivation as such:

> to deal with the problem of creating objects without having to specify the exact class of the object that will be created.

And later on:

> Creating an object often requires complex processes not appropriate to include within a composing object. The object's creation may lead to a significant duplication of code, may require information not accessible to the composing object, may not provide a sufficient level of abstraction, or may otherwise not be part of the composing object's concerns. The factory method design pattern handles these problems by defining a separate method for creating the objects, which subclasses can then override to specify the derived type of product that will be created.

Ok my assumptions are as follows: I'm writing code, and in my code I want to use the "products" - either a `MagicRoom` or an `OrdinaryRoom`. Now, instead of instantiating those in my client code, the Factory pattern says: don't do this! Rather, create another tree of classes which defines a `createRoom` method which will create the appropriate room. Now, instantiate **this** object and use `createRoom`. So I don't understand - if in my client code I don't  want to "have to specify the exact class of the object that will be created" - how does this pattern helps me? I still need to specify which "creator" class I want to instantiate?

And as for the second quote about "require information not accessible to the composing object". I also don't understand - what kind of information will be in the creator class (e.g. `OrdinaryMazeGame`) which is not accessible in the client code?

The only thing I **could** think of being useful is if in my client code I have **a lot**
of instantiations, and I want to be able to quickly change to another class, then instead of having a lot of `room = new MagicRoom` which I'll need to change to `room = new OrdinaryRoom` - I will have a single object with the `makeRoom` so I'll only need to change the type of this object from `MagicMazeGame` to `OrdinaryMazeGame`. Is this the **core**
benefit of this design pattern?

It seems that all the examples out there about Factory Method pattern are so simple that the point of using just doesn't appear in these examples. Can someone give a good example

Comment: Your very last paragraph describes a problem I have with a lot of patterns.

Comment: The assumption is something like: you're writing a customizable library that other people can extend, and you have points in your logic where you need to instantiate objects of an unknown type (to be chosen, or even created, by the users of your library). The Factory method hierarchy can be separate from your core logic, but doesn't have to be. See my answer [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/431193/275536) for more details.

Comment: @FilipMilovanović, why isn't this assumption presented anywhere? Seems like it is a fundemental requirement...

Comment: The primary source, the [GoF book](https://www.amazon.com/Design-Patterns-Object-Oriented-Addison-Wesley-Professional-ebook/dp/B000SEIBB8), actually opens with a "Motivation" section where they explain this. If you haven't come across this framing of the problem, it's because all of the online information represents secondary sources, and many authors either fail to express this clearly, or don't really understand the pattern itself. The maze example is actually from later on in the book, they use it to illustrate how to implement the pattern, but they don't lead with it.

Comment: @FilipMilovanović, so you're saying that, say when I build a standalone application (not a library or framework that I want to enable clients to extend) - and I know the kinds of products I want to use - there is no point using this pattern? It seems weird that so many people got it wrong..

Comment: @YoavKlein the pattern is potentially useful, even in a standalone application, as soon as you use interfaces or subclassing and have loose coupling between your app components. There are people using this pattern without even knowing it’s a pattern.

Comment: Well, the key idea is that you have a piece of business logic that at some point needs to create a certain abstract type (and operate on it), but also needs to stay independent of the concrete type - it leaves that decision to *something else*. Frameworks of the kind I mentioned provide a good example of how this need might arise, but as Christophe said, you can have a similarly reusable component even within a standalone application, resulting from separation of concerns, providing a DRY way to have similar variants, or letting you support future requirements by extending existing code. 1/2

Comment: Or, perhaps you want your application to support multiple platforms, and you have some piece of platform-independent logic (defined in the base classes) that involves creating a platform-specific resource, that, once created, can be used in a platform-independent way - so you provide an implementation for each platform. These are different scenarios that have a need for a similar kind of separation of concerns. But yeah, if you don't need that, then there's no need to apply it - the pattern is not something you default to, but something you deliberately use to allow for that separation. 2/2

Comment: P.S. Also, as I mentioned in the linked answer, today most languages support lambdas, which can play the role that the virtual factory method in the base class has in the traditional pattern - if all you need is a single factory method. So, you have a simplified version of this pattern any time you inject a lambda that creates some other object, but returns it as some interface or base type, and than call that lambda somewhere in the logic within the containing class,

Comment: Just buy the Gang of Four Design Patterns book.  That not only has good explanations and motivations for each pattern, it also has a sample application that shows the real world use of each pattern.  It's well worth the money.

Comment: @YoavKlein: several of the GoF patterns are most useful when creating libraries or frameworks which should be reused or extended by a client who cannot change the libraries' code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The aim of the factory method is according to GoF:

> Define an interface for creating an object, but let subclasses decide which class to instantiate. Factory Method lets a class defer instantiation to subclasses.

The challenge in explaining the motivation is that the pattern has several flavors that address slightly different creational needs, depending on whether is is provided by an abstract class or a concrete class, and whether is is parameterized (i.e. the parameters of the factory method tell which `Shape` to instantiate) or not.

As you pointed out, the factory method can be a way to easily switch to antoher class being created, by isolating the creation in the method. But it also allows to select at runtime which class to create, by instantiating a different creator. Last but not least, the factory method also allows to inject a factory into other class that is unaware of what to create or how to chose the specific class to instantiate.

In Gof there are several pages to describe all these aspects. The main common idea is to decouple the creation of instances.

Answer (score 0):

When you instantiate a class, you normally provide the class and some arguments. That will likely be repeated throughout your code.

When you use a factory, you don’t specify which class you instantiate at all. Best case, you give a description of what you use the instance for, and the factory will decide for you which class is instantiated to best support your use cases. If someone creates a new class, that class could be instantiated without any change in the caller. If you do unit testing, an instance of a mocked class could be returned. If you have different classes that are all compatible but optimised for different purposes, you might always get the best optimised one.

Yes, code to instantiate different classes will be there, in the factory method. But it’s there only once, and the author of the factory method will know best which class to instantiate. Much better than a random caller elsewhere.

Comment: _Yes, code to instantiate different classes will be there, in the factory method_ - Well, you're right that the instantiation of products will be in the factory method, but the instantiation of the factory object will be in the caller, and that was my question.